# Tool to catch and log javascript errors for embeddable library

Tags: javascript, logging, error-handling

I have implemented an AMD javascript library embeddable on any webpage.

I wish that every time my library get an error is sent to a log app server.

I have tried this solution: https://errorception.com but If in the page that includes the library exits another errorception script and id, a conflict will occur.

I am finding a solution that:
1. Log only my library error
2. does not create conflict problem with other instances

can you give me some advice?

Comment: Quick and dirty solution could be just firing an XMLHttpRequest when an error is caught?

Comment: Yes of course, but I want know if exists tool like errorception that it works well with embedabble library